# Is there an error in Nestjs gateways documentation?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to use socket.io with Nestjs.
Nestjs gateway documentation says "The gateway is now listening, but we have not yet subscribed to any incoming messages. Let's create a handler that will subscribe to the events messages and respond to the user with the exact same data." and give the following code.

```
@SubscribeMessage('events')
handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): string {
  return data;
}
```

Pay your attention that they use just a return for answering.
When I try to repeat this code, Postman desktop app doesn't receive any answer from my server.

People say that I have to use socket.emit to answer to the client and it works but I have some doubts. I can't believe that Nest could have just forgotten to say about it in their documentation.
Is that an error in Nestjs documentation or I just don't understand something?